# GitLab CI headless chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to set up CI with gitlab and my e2e tests rely on chrome headless which works locally , how can I be sure that I have this headless functionality with chrome in the CI process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AngularJS you can get started right away with [docker-e2e-protractor](https://hub.docker.com/r/hortonworks/docker-e2e-protractor/) or check out the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-e2e-protractor/blob/master/Dockerfile) and modify it to your needs to fit your framework.

It integrates nicely into Gitlab CI. I use it in combination with an AngularJS frontend Docker image connected to a CakePHP backend Docker image and then use docker-e2e-protractor to run the tests.

Comment: Funnily enough, I saw your answer elsewhere regarding this issue and sought to take that approach , thanks